# How do I set the PATH environment variable to point to JRE version 1.5

Tags: path, command-line-interface, java

Hi there I have a program that requires me to set the PATH
environment variable to point to JRE version 1.5 as I need to access the program via a command prompt. So any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Please include as much details about your environment as you can when posting questions.  This process is completely different for different operating systems.  It's even different for different editions of the same operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Test the change by running "PATH=${PATH}:(your additional directory here)" and, if everything works as intended, edit the "PATH=" line in ~/.bash_login to automatically use the new configuraiton.

This [PATH HowTo](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Path.html) should cover further questions, if needed.

Comment: This should work, but the ~/.bash_profile is more typical location for environment variable settings.  Also, if you have a .bash_profile, .bash_login does not get executed

Answer (score 0):

"Go to the control panel > System > Advanced and edit your environment variables there. Append "; C:\path\to\the\jre\bin" to the PATH variable. Open a new terminal and profit."

Answer provided by Borealid